# Как вставить файл с кириллицей в название в iframe?

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется такой код вывода pdf файла на странице в iframe

```
<iframe src="<?= Yii::$app->params['mainURL']?>content/users/award/<?=$model->file_name;?>" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

Выводим мы файлы, которые загрузил на сайт пользователь. Но если файл идёт в названии с кириллицей, то возникает проблема в том, что файл не может быть найден. На сервере используется кодировка cp1251

Пробовал в самом iframe перекодировать название с помощью `iconv()`

```
<iframe src="<?= iconv("UTF-8", 'cp1251', Yii::$app->params['mainURL'] . 'content/users/award/'. $model->file_name);?>" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

Проблема осталась на месте. При этом вручную с сервера я могу скачать и открыть файл. Как быть?

Comment: urldecode($model->file_name)

Comment: @user334685, не подошло. Файл по прежнему не найден

Comment: давайте тогда саму ссылку на этот кириллический файл, который у вас вручную  с сервера вы можете скачть

Comment: urlencode($file_name), я не туда глянул